# KeyBoard Shortcut for opening terminal from existing directory

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, shortcuts

I need to open terminal using shortcut in any directory as I can in the file browser like this:

[image]

Comment: An alternative with Guake I used during my brief Unity time can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152193/how-to-open-directory-in-guake-from-nautilus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it still works on Ubuntu, but right clicking in the directory (must be opened on Nautilus) and selecting Open Terminal Here...

Comment: Is there any keyboard shortcut for that?

Comment: Well, I searched and found [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here) maybe it would help you :)

Comment: Okay. I'll go through that.